How to get pandas to run on a python executable in a virtual environment
I'm trying to run an executable in a virtual environment. Pyinstaller is used to make my script an executable file. When I launch the exe it is giving me an error message that is posted below first.
My python script is posted last.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas to the virtual environment, which has not changed the error message.
'''
(venv_py312) 
C:\Users\mberardi\venv_py312\Scripts\dist\Tank_Stress_Data>Tank_Stress_Data.exe
pandas\io\sql.py:912: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable 
(engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 
objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

running main datafrome

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tank_Stress_Data.py", line 85, in <module>
File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 333, in wrapper
File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 2417, in to_excel
File "pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 952, in write
File "pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 490, in _write_cells
File "openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 218, in value
File "openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 197, in _bind_value
File "openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 165, in check_string
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError:

none



cannot be used in worksheets.
[22740] Failed to execute script 'Tank_Stress_Data' due to unhandled exception!
'''

import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time
from socket import gethostname
import filecmp
from shutil import copyfile
from smb import smb_structs
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

filepath = "U:/Users2/PLATING/Electroforming Tool Board - Python Data/Tank_Stress_Data_imported.xlsx"
#filename = "Tank_Stress_Data_imported.xlsx"
filename = "Tank_Stress_Data_imported.xlsx"

main = "U:/Users2/PLATING/Electroforming Tool Board - Python Data/Tank_Stress_Data_main.xlsx"
imported = "U:/Users2/PLATING/Electroforming Tool Board - Python Data/Tank_Stress_Data_imported.xlsx"



def get_password():
    passwordFile= 'U:/Users2/PLATING/8265.txt'
    emailPassword = open(passwordFile)
    file_contents = list(emailPassword.readlines())
    return file_contents[0].strip()

def upload(username, password, my_name, remote_name, remote_ip, path, filename, service_name):
    conn = connect(username, password, my_name, remote_name, remote_ip)

    
    if conn:
        print('Upload = ' + path + filename)
        print('Size = %.lf kB' % (os.path.getsize(filepath) / 1024.0))
        print('start upload')
#        with open(filepath, 'rb') as file_obj:
#            filesize = conn.storeFile(service_name, path+filename, file_obj)
        print('upload finished')
        conn.close()
def connect(username, password, my_name, remote_name, remote_ip):
    '''
    Creates an SMB connection object to a server
    '''
    smb_structs.SUPPORT_SMB2 = True
    conn= SMBConnection(username, password, my_name, remote_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
    
    try:
        conn.connect(remote_ip, 139)
        return conn
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return

username = 'OPTSservice'
password = get_password()
my_name = gethostname()
remote_name = 'OPTSFS01'
remote_ip = '192.168.7.249'
path = '/Users2/PLATING/Electroforming Tool Board - Python Data/'
service_name = 'sys2'

go = True

try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=OPTSAPPS02,1433\\SQLEXPRESS;'
                          'Database=OPTS Production Tracking Service;'
                          'UID=fetch;'
                          'PWD=Reader123')

    query = """SELECT ID, Tank, Stress, Strip, Time, Constant, Units, Main, I_AUX, U_AUX, IAUX_MAIN, REMARK, DATE, OPERATOR FROM Tank_Stress"""

    DF = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
        
    print('running main datafrome')
    DF.to_excel("U:\\Users2\\PLATING\\Electroforming Tool Board - Python Data\\" + "Tank_Stress_Data_main" +
                ".xlsx",index = False)
except OSError as err:
    print("Error:", err)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    go = False
    
try:
    print("CHECKING FILE: " + str(datetime.now()))
    if not filecmp.cmp(main, imported):
        copyfile(main, imported)
        print("UPDATED")
        upload(username, password, my_name, remote_name, remote_ip, path, filename, service_name)
        print("UPLOADING FILE")
    else:
        pass
except OSError as err:
    print("Error:", err)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    go = False

